# Spring boot war project add as a dependency in another spring boot war project

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa, war

I have two spring boot war. one war is dependent to another. I am provided the dependency to the parent pom as well. But while deploying some times i got the below error and some time it will work properly in apache tomact.

error:
... 89 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.FileProcess.DataInterfaceEntities.FileFormatsEntityTemp
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:582)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:85)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:75)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:229)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:162)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:72)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$6(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:326)
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230)
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784)
... 100 more

Child pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.UserManagementMerge</groupId>
    <artifactId>UserManagementMerge</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>UserManagementMerge</name>
    <description>UserManagementMerge</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
            
        
        
           <!-- JSTL for JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For JSP compilation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            
             <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

child main:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.User.*"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories({"com.User.UserManagementRepository","com.User.CommonRepository"})
@EntityScan({"com.User.UserManagementEntities","com.User.CommonEntities"})

public class Um1Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Um1Application.class, args);
    }
    
    

}
```

Parent pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.FileProcess</groupId>
    <artifactId>FileProcess</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>FileProcess</name>
    <description>FileProcess</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
         <start-class>com.FileProcess.FileProcess.Um1ApplicationPine</start-class> 
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        
        
        
        
           <!-- JSTL for JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For JSP compilation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    
 
      <dependency> 
        <groupId>com.UserManagementMerge</groupId>
    <artifactId>UserManagementMerge</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type> 
      </dependency>    
    
     <dependency>
 <groupId>com.UserManagementMerge</groupId>
    <artifactId>UserManagementMerge</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <classifier>classes</classifier>
</dependency>  
    
    
    
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.FileProcess.FileProcess.Um1ApplicationFile</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
        
            
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

parent main:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.User.*","com.FileProcess.*"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories({"com.User.UserManagementRepository","com.User.CommonRepository","com.FileProcess.DataInterfaceRepository"})
@EntityScan({"com.User.UserManagementEntities","com.User.CommonEntities","com.FileProcess.DataInterfaceEntities"})

public class Um1ApplicationFile {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Um1ApplicationPine.class, args);
    }
    
    

}
```

Comment: You cannot use a war as a dependency as a war is a deployable artifact (regardless if you use Spring bOot or not).

Comment: but when using .  <configuration>
            <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
        </configuration>.    jar will be created and what about maven overlay concept.

Comment: But why is running properly in some times

Comment: You can use a jar but not a war as a dependency. Also Spring bOot jar files have a different structure compared to regular jar files (as explained in the reference guide). I strongly suggest a read of the documentation of the frameworks you use instead of using things you don't understand.